# MySql table in phpmailer body

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I would like to send a user a email with an html table in it.
The information of the table must come from my MySql table
Normally I do it this way:

```
<?php
$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE email='$email'");   //
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)) {
?>
<body>
    <table>
        <?php
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['item'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
<?php
}
?>
```

But how can I do this in this situation:

```
 $mail             = new PHPMailer();
    $test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE email='$email'");   //
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)) {
        $body = '
        <p>Thank you !</p>
        <p>here is your result</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>[Info from db]</td>
            </tr>
        </table><br>
        <p>Greetings !</p>
        ';
    }
    $body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
    $mail->IsSMTP();
```

Thanks !

Comment: concatenate in the loop only the new line `<tr> ... </tr>`. Add the opening part and the closing part after the loop. Aside: please note that the mysql_* functions are deprecated and the POSIX regexp extension too. I would recommend using PDO or mysqli and PCRE.

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: @VMai Thanks for the tip ! Upgraded to MySqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `echo`ing the data you get from the database you should write it into the `$body`.

```
$body = '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)) {
    $body .= '<tr><td>' . $row['item'] . '</td></tr>';
}
$body .= '</table>';
```

The assignment `.=` appends the specified string to an existing variable.